# CURL disable issue

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have been getting error code 60 when i attempting to get data from facebook API with PHP SDk.

To resolve this we need to disable with

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` in base_facebook.php.

So, Does this makes curl certification verification for all sites on my server?.

Comment: not it dose not affects all of your server , just this curl request will be affected.

Comment: Update your SDK with latest certificate file

Comment: @Anvesh : How long the certificate remains valid?

Comment: Sorry my mistake up there...actually they have changed the certificate file bundled with the SDK. The certificate earlier in use was valid until April 2013, I don't know about the one available now but as per their comments they have updated cert bundle to use the current curl bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Update your SDK to 3.2.1. The cert file needs updating.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/commit/42961c500761dd62099bf633a5db7182c00c1678

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question, just quote from [`curl_setopt` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> Sets an option on the given cURL session handle.

So no, it affect just your current session handle (**only one** instance of cURL handle in your **current** script).